# Filter multiple list field items in IQueryable list using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a class for a contact like this:

```
public class contacts
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string Mobile {get;set;}
   public string Email {get;set;}
}
```

From my repository I need to filter contacts with multiple fields and multiple value. How could I do this? My searching list will be like this JSON

```
[
  { “Name”, “Alan”, “Mobile ” : “0000000000”},
  { “Name”, “Milan”, “Mobile” : “0000000001”, “Email ” : “test@test.com” }
]
```

What is the better way to call the filtering?

Comment: Its not clear what you wanting to filter by (and that is not valid json)

Comment: i need to filter the list of contacts from repository with this json value in one shot, the json may be change with respect to the request

Comment: `“Name”, “Alan”`, seems to be incorrect json, will be better to write a class like `contactfilter` and deserialize the your json to populate the list of contactfilter and then you can use it in linq.

Comment: As I noted, its not even valid (it would need to be `"Name": "Alan"` etc). Are you wanting to get all records with either `Name="Alan" && Mobile="0000000000"`  **or** `Name="Milan" && Mobile="0000000001" && Email="test@test.com"`. And where is that json coming from and are you converting to a collection of objects?

Answer (score 0):

First make the JSON to a proper JSON as it looks incorrect. Not sure whether you have the json in front end or back end. If it is in front end, send it to back end using AJAX and convert it to list using newtonsoft json. Then filter using below query.

```
var filtered = allContacts.Where(x=>jsonContacts.Any(y=>y.Name == x.Name || y.Mobile==x.Mobile || y.Email==x.Email));
```

If you want to filter like find all contacts which matches the few characters even(%like%), then use Contains or Starts with or wild card to find.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're looking for is a Where() and FirstOrDefault() combination.
This means you could write a method that takes two contacts, one you're testing, and one you're looking for.

```
IsMatchingContact(var contactToTest, var contactToFind){
    if(contactToFind.Name != null){
        if(contactToTest.Name != contactToFind.Name){
            return false
        }
    }
    if(contactToFind.Mobile != null){
        if(contactToTest.Mobile != contactToFind.Mobile){
            return false
        }
    }
    if(contactToFind.Email != null){
        if(contactToTest.Email != contactToFind.Email){
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

I think the above method could be written more succinctly, and would appreciate any feedback people have on making better use of the goodies C# has to accomplish it.

You then combine this with the Where and FirstOrDefault on any collection implementing IEnumerable, lets assume that you've taken the JSON and created an object contactIWantToFind with it.

```
collectionOfContacts
    .Where(x => IsMatchingContact(x, contactIWantToFind))
    .FirstOrDefault()
```

If you were wanting to return a collection of all matches, remove the FirstOrDefault() method